# Natural Language Understanding - IBM Tool

Tags: nlp, keyword, nlu

I have written 2000 words of content to analyse in IBM toolm for natural language processing. And i want to target "foods for acidity" keyword in my content but it is not showing any relevancy for this particular word and even that not picking up in the keyword. What are the html attributes to my keywords that this tool will show "foods for acidity" on the top.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOIHP.png)

Content: